Adding item to ListView in Kotlin
I am new at Kotlin and Android
I have such main activity
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnControlButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Checking" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

and such ListView item layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:inputType="text"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor,RelativeOverlap" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

I want to add item to ListView when users types in any item "add new item".
Please show me the right code in Kotlin.

I think it might be worth to include some of the code that actually references the views you pasted in, that will help us determine the language + what fetures (such as viewBinding) are you using :)

I tried to do this on mayself, but I failed, so I get every working code for this task. It will be nice if the code will be as simple as possible. Language is a Kotlin. Enviroment Android Studio

I think the best thing would be to load the list with an adapter, then just update the list to add a new element:
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    Button addButton;
    String[] ListElements = new String[] {
        "Element1",
        "Element2"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);
        addButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final List < String > elementsArray = new ArrayList <String>(Arrays.asList(ListElements));

        final ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String >
            (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item, R.id.textInput, elementsArray);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                elementsArray.add("Element3");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}

tell me how it goes

the post has a kotlin tag, it is safe to assume the OP is using Kotlin in his project as well

I want to add new item when user types in any list item "add new item", not using button. Button is for another taks. Please show me the working code for this task, because I tried it on my owne but I failed.

I didn't understand the "add new element" thing, I do it with a button, on the other hand I tried the code and it's fine, just fix this line:
final ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String >
(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item, R.id.textInput, elementsArray);

In your code you add new item to List when user clicks button. I want to add new element to list when user types "add new item" in ListView item in textInput element.

Careful with variable names, Addbutton can be mistaken for a class, it's a good practice to start variable names with lowercase letter e.g. addButton.

You must work the listview with adapter, then in the adapter you detect the event when I write "add new element"

I know this, but I cant find working code. So I asked more skilled people to help me to do it. Note, that I try to write my first app in Cotlin.


You need custom adapter for list view Custom Adapter ListView
Add listener on text change EditText option 1 or option 2
Add if statement to check whether the text inputted in EditText is "add new element"
if true add new item to the list then notifyDataSetChanged()

Some recommendation:

Its gonna be so much easier to develop & maintain using RecyclerView instead of ListView read more here
lowercase() your inputted string first before comparing "add new element"
Remove onTextChangeListener when out of focus, add it when in focus
Play around with viewType to prevent bug like this How to fix item not consistent in RecyclerView (sorry i didn't find any English article)

Good luck on your journey to become Android Developer cheers!

I cooked code using your suggestion, but it doesnt work. I cant put this code to the comment because it is to long. How to show you my code using Stack overflow?
